# 2D Driving Game with Unity

Tags: unity, c#, gui, control, car

I'm trying to make a 2D car driving game in Unity and I'm having problems with my code.

I am able to move forward,backward,turn left/right using arrow key from my present code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CarControll : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
float speedForce = 15f;
float torqueForce = -200f;
float driftFactorSticky = 0.9f;
float driftFactorSlippy = 1;
float maxStickyVelocity = 2.5f;
float minSlippyVelocity = 1.5f; 

bool move=false;
public bool forwardArrow=false;
public bool backwardArrow=false;

public bool rightTurn=false;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

void Update() {

    move=true;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () {


    Rigidbody2D rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();


    float driftFactor = driftFactorSticky;
    if(RightVelocity().magnitude > maxStickyVelocity) {
        driftFactor = driftFactorSlippy;
    }

    rb.velocity = ForwardVelocity() + RightVelocity()*driftFactor;

    if( Input.GetButton("Accelerate") || Input.GetButtonDown("Forward") || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
        Debug.Log ("Uparrow....................................................");
        rb.AddForce( transform.up * 20);


    }

    if( forwardArrow==true) {

        rb.AddForce(transform.up*0.5f);
    }

    if(backwardArrow==true) {

    rb.AddForce( transform.up * -speedForce/25f );
    }

    if(Input.GetButton("Brakes") || Input.GetButton("Backword") || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow)) {

        rb.AddForce( transform.up * -speedForce/2f );   
    }

        float tf = Mathf.Lerp (0, torqueForce, rb.velocity.magnitude / 2);
        rb.angularVelocity = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * tf;

}

Vector2 ForwardVelocity() {

    return transform.up * Vector2.Dot( GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity, transform.up );
}

Vector2 RightVelocity() {

    return transform.right * Vector2.Dot( GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity, transform.right );
}

public void MoveForward()  //forward button
{
    forwardArrow = true;
    backwardArrow = false;
}

public void MoveBackward() backward button
{
    backwardArrow = true;
    forwardArrow = false;
}

public void RightTurn()  //right button
{

    rightTurn = true;
}
```

}

I have added four button(Forward,backward,right,left).Now I need to move the car using this button. The car is moving Forward,backward using the button but when Press the right/left button the car is not Turing left/right while move.But its working perfectly on key press.Can anyboady help solving this issue

Answer (score -1):

First a small side note: you may have a typo

```
if(Input.GetButton("Brakes") || Input.GetButton("Backword")
```

With "Backword" did you mean "Backward"?

---

Since I don't find any Input.GetButton("left") or Input.GetButton("right") I assume that you use Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") for left and right.

In that case I guess you have to map your buttons to controll the horizontal axis. The keyboard keys are already mapped to control the horizontal axis.
In the menu of Unity take a look into Edit / Project Settings / Input. There are the mappings.

I don't know if you can map them to UI buttons though. I haven't worked a lot with the UI so far. You will need something like if UI button down set a variable (e.g. moveLeft) to true and if if UI button is released set the variable (e.g. moveLeft) to false and change your code in that way.

[This question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/843319/46-gui-button-onrelease.html) recommends adding EventTriggers to the button to do that.

Comment: turing left/right is working but the problem is that when I click a button to turn right,its getting rotating towards right continuously.I need to turn only on a button click.Its working smoothly using keypress